# What is the meaning of abbreviation »'n« and »'ne«?

Tags: meaning, abbreviation

> 'n ganz normaler Tag
>   'ne Suche gibt es nicht

Could anyone tell me what these abbreviations *'n* and *'ne* mean?

Comment: See also http://www.atlas-alltagssprache.de/runde-5/f18a-b/

Answer (score 15):

Both are abbrevations of forms of *ein/eine*

- 'n ganz normaler Tag - ***ein** ganz Normaler Tag*
- 'ne Suche gibt es nicht - ***eine** Suche gibt es nicht*

Note that both abbreviations are very colloquial and only used in everyday speech in some parts of Germany.

Comment: What parts of Germany would that be?

Comment: Certainly the southern parts of Germany, but I had the impression that this shortening was used everywhere.

Comment: @Austinh1 actually, I would say that the southern regions of Germany do not use these abbreviations but people from northern parts do. Southern parts - I am thinking of Bavaria - and Austrian dialects rather use _a [ein, eine]_ and _an [einen]_

Comment: @Loong already posted a link to maps showing the (approximate) current regional distribution.

Comment: True, I didn't live in the dialect heavy part of south Germany, just in the city Munich. So that may be why I have a skewed impression.

Answer (score 8):

It is not an abbreviation, this is slang or dialect, used in northern parts of German spoken area (you rarely will hear it in Austria).

"N" stands for "ein", "ne" stands for "eine":

> N ganz normaler Tag.
>   Ein ganz normaler Tag.
>
> Dat is ne Kuh.
>   Das ist eine Kuh.

In southern regions (Bavaria, Austria) people use an other slang word for those articles. It is "a" for both, "ein" and "eine":

> A ganz normala Tåg.
>   Ein ganz normaler Tag.
>
> Des is a Kua.
>   Das ist eine Kuh.

Comment: If it’s slang, they can still be considered abbreviations: Northern slang uses the last part and Southwestern slang uses the first part of standard _ein(e)_ (it’s more obvious if spoken or transcribed phonemically: /ˈaɪ̯n(ə)/). A perfect example of how a _Dachsprache_ works. If it’s dialect, however, we may consider separate but synonymous words. Interestingly, _’n_ is extended to _nen_ by some speakers (which resembles _’nen_ from _einen_ of course). Also, spoken language tends to shorten further, e.g. /das.nə.ku:/ (when _ist_ is not emphasized).